# Function to remove class isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove class with `removeClass()`

but there is not work

here is my code

```
<td ng-repeat="user in users[0].yds" data-title="'Timeline'"
    sortable="timeline" style="text-align: center">
    <i id="circle_show" class="icon-circle-blank" style="position: absolute;">
    </i>
</td>

 $('#circle_show').removeClass("icon-circle-blank");
 console.log('rm')
```

`removeClass()` have done , but the class is not remove

please help

Comment: If you want to removeClass from all <i> tag then use class instead of ID.

Comment: Your question is using jquery for the removing of the class.  Take a look at the angulr ng-class, for a more angular way of doing it. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass  also with the ng-repeat you are potentially setting more than 1 element with the same ID, which you shouldn't do

Comment: if I want to add class , use class to add is not work?

Comment: @user2680731 Your attempt indicates you don't "get" the Angular way just way. Fear not! I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td ng-repeat="user in users[0].yds" data-title="'Timeline'" sortable="timeline"    style="text-align: center" >

<i class="circle_show icon-circle-blank" style="position: absolute;"></i>
```

```
 $('.circle_show').removeClass("icon-circle-blank");
 console.log('rm')
```